# table in latex - unwanted breaks in rows

Tags: tables, columns

In the below table I added `\\` at the start to create a space between the variables, which worked, but now I have this gap- no border between the rows in the column that was initially there- as seen in screenshot- how do I get rid of these gaps again? Many thankss

[image]

code is:

```
% Uncomment the following line to allow the usage of graphics (.png, .jpg)
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% Comment the following line to NOT allow the usage of umlauts
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% Start the document
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
        \centering % Centre the table on the slide
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \toprule
            Name & Equation & Description & Variables\\
            \toprule
Reynolds & $Re=\frac{g}{g}$ & desc  & \shortstack{$\mu$- dynamic viscosity \\ v- velocity \\ L \\ $\rho $- density  }\\
\\ Ohnesorge & $Oh=\frac{f}{g}$ & $\rho$  & \shortstack{$\mu$ \\ $\sigma$- surface-tension coefficient \\ L \\ $\rho$ }\\ 
\\ Weber & We &  $\frac{ff}{ff}$ & \shortstack{$\nu$ \\ $\sigma$ \\ L \\ $\rho$ }\\
            


            
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
            
        \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use vertical rules `|` with booktabs, it's designed againt these pipes.

Comment: Replace \\ \\ with \\ & & & \\

Comment: thanks @leandriis that worked :))

Answer (score 3):

I would write your tables like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering % Centre the table on the slide
    \linespread{0.84}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{lccl}
    \toprule
Name        & Equation & Description & Variables\\
    \midrule
Reynolds    & $Re=\frac{g}{g}$ & desc   & \makecell[l]{$\mu$: dynamic viscosity \\ 
                                                        $v$: velocity \\ 
                                                        L \\ 
                                                        $\rho$: density }\\
    \addlinespace[6pt]
Ohnesorge   & $Oh=\frac{f}{g}$ & $\rho$ & \makecell[l]{$\mu$: dynamic viscosity \\
                                                        $v$: velocity \\
                                                        L \\
                                                        $\rho$: density }\\
    \addlinespace[6pt]
Weber       & We      & $\frac{ff}{ff}$ & \makecell[l]{$\nu$ \\ 
                                                       $\sigma$ \\ 
                                                       L \\ 
                                                       $\rho$ }\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

As in [@Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572833/5001), I'd do away with all vertical lines -- trust me, they're not needed, and they won't be missed. I'd also left-align the cell contents, top-align the cell contents across rows, replace the second `\toprule` directive with `\midrule`, and replace the all-blank lines with the less profligate `\addlinespace`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule, and \addlinespace macros
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \smash[b] macro

% Start the document
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering % Centre the table horizontally
    \begin{tabular}{@{} llll @{}} % suggestion: use 'l', not 'c', col. type
    \toprule
    Name & Equation & Description & Variables\\
    \midrule
    Reynolds & $\mathit{Re}=\smash[b]{\frac{g}{g}}$ & desc  
      & $\mu$ -- dynamic viscosity \\ 
    &&& $v$ -- velocity \\ 
    &&& $L$ \\
    &&& $\rho$ -- density  \\ 
    \addlinespace % <-- new
    Ohnesorge & $\mathit{Oh}=\smash{\frac{f}{g}}$ & $\rho$  
      & $\mu$ \\ 
    &&& $\sigma$ -- surface-tension coeff. \\ 
    &&& $L$ \\ 
    &&& $\rho$ \\  
    \addlinespace % <-- new
    Weber & $\mathit{We}$ &  $\smash{\frac{ff}{ff}}$ 
      & $\nu$ \\ 
    &&& $\sigma$ \\ 
    &&& $L$ \\ 
    &&& $\rho$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want vertical rules compatible with the horizontal rules of `booktabs` (even if it is not at all in the spirit of `booktabs`), you can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% Start the document
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering % Centre the table on the slide
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\toprule
Name & Equation & Description & Variables\\
\toprule
Reynolds & $Re=\frac{g}{g}$ & desc  & \shortstack{$\mu$- dynamic viscosity \\ v- velocity \\ L \\ $\rho $- density  }\\
\\ Ohnesorge & $Oh=\frac{f}{g}$ & $\rho$  & \shortstack{$\mu$ \\ $\sigma$- surface-tension coefficient \\ L \\ $\rho$ }\\ 
\\ Weber & We &  $\frac{ff}{ff}$ & \shortstack{$\nu$ \\ $\sigma$ \\ L \\ $\rho$ }\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

I recommend the design in the spirit of `booktabs` as described in others answers.